# Where is the place of other 40 MB that git installation used on my hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, cleanup

After I did:

```
apt install git
```

terminal said that:

```
After this operation, 43.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

I agreed. After installation I did:

```
df -h
```

and saw that 43.3 MB was really used.
Then I did:

```
whereis git
```

and found out two paths where git is placed:

```
git: /usr/bin/git /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
```

To know how much space does it take on my hdd, I did:

```
ls -la /usr/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3212468 Apr 19 20:19 /usr/bin/git
ls -la /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15170 Apr 19 20:19 /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
```

So, I found approximately 3 MB in first path and 15 KB in second path.
The question is: Where is the place of other 40 MB that git installation used on my hdd?

Comment: My /home directory is placed on another hdd (/dev/sdb5). There is a lot of free space. But I am asking about space that git installation used on /dev/sda1. As I said before - I saw decreasing of free space on /dev/sda1 after git installation.

Comment: this has 26M on my machine: `/usr/lib/git-core/`. And `/usr/share/doc/git/` has another 3M.

Comment: Yes. Thank you, pLumo.